# How to create a colored textbox in beamer?

Tags: beamer, box

AI am trying to use the following to create a box (preferably with no title) in a beamer presentation. Unfortunately, it does not work! How should I modify it to make it work. FYI: it works for a document type that's an article.

```
\documentclass[pdf]{beamer}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  colback=Magenta!5!white,
  colframe=Magenta!75!black,
  title={\centering Homework}]
The math problem should be here...
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In your question you write "preferrably with no title"  but your code contains a `title`. Could you please clarify on that?

Comment: That was my mistake. I commented out the title command. Thanks for the answer! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `beamer` class already loads the `xcolor` package, your code results in the following error message: `Option clash for package xcolor.`. To overcome this, I have removed `\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}` and replaced it by the class option `[xcolor={dvisnames}]`. I have also enclosed the `tcolorbox` in a `frame` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[xcolor={dvipsnames}]{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz,lipsum,lmodern}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame} 
\begin{tcolorbox}[
  colback=Magenta!5!white,
  colframe=Magenta!75!black,
  title={\centering Homework}]
The math problem should be here...
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```